# Vue.js data in child instances

Tags: vue.js

How can i include `data` option in child instances in Vue.js?

```
<html>
    <body>
        {{ foo }}

        <script>
            var root = new Vue({
                el: 'body'
            });

            var child = new Vue({
                parent: root,
                data: function() {
                    foo: 'bar'
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here nothing is getting printed in the `body`. But if i add the `foo` variable inside the root instance, it's getting printed. How to make the data option work for child instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the syntax is to have [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) attribute in a child vue instance:

```
const Foo = { 
    data: function () {
    return {
        foo: "I am Foo"
      }
    },
    template: '<div>foo: {{foo}}</div>' 
}
```

and you can use this data property only in the template of child instance. You can see the whole working demo in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mimani/teyg39z8/).

Another style of creating a vue component and using it can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/qatomaqori/1/edit?html,js,console,output), with JS code.

```
Vue.component('child', {
  data () {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
     }
  },
  template: '#foo'
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#root'
});
```